# How to use Win+Tab with scrolling?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm using Autohotkey and i want to make it use Win+Tab for Ctrl+scroll like this:

```
~Ctrl & WheelDown::Send #{Tab}
~Ctrl & WheelUp::Send #+{Tab}
```

However scrolling up doesn't work at all and scrolling down shows a flip3d preview for about a quarterr of a second, not actually tabbing anywhere. What needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's firing when you press control and mouse, and never again.
Simply swapping the # out for an

```
{LWin Down}
```

'works', as in tabs, but a little more work needs to be done to get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Win + tab does that. Try it with the keyboard now!

You want to HOLD Win + Tab + Tab to change the window. Or use Alt+tab to change instantly.

I'm not sure why these are different- Win+Tab really only shows flip 3D but doesn't change anything on release, Alt+tab does.